# Load podcast directory in my iphone app

Tags: ios4, ios5, podcast

I am creating a app that loads itunes podcast directory in my iphone app.

and user can see it and download it to app.

i am trying to find how we can load itunes podcast directory to our app?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way of doing that.

Apple provides such apis to get the data from podcast.

we can parse the data from api and load it to app.

and then you can download it.

thanks